# How to extract part of string using regex

Tags: regex, go

I am trying to extract a part of a string as date-timestamp.

Example string:

```
Upgrade starting on Mon Aug 9 06:46:00 UTC 2021 with ...
```

Extracted values should be:

```
Mon Aug 9 06:46:00 UTC 2021
```

I tried applying the following regex to extract the timestamp:

```
(\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2})
```

How can I extract the day month and year as well.

Comment: `^(Upgrade starting on )(\S{3}) (\S{3}) (\d{1,2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (\S{3}) (\d{4})(.*)` https://regex101.com/r/g4AHf4/1   This should help you get on the way

Comment: Excluding first part: `(?<=Upgrade starting on )(\S{3}) (\S{3}) (\d{1,2}) (\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}) (\S{3}) (\d{4})(.*)`

Comment: If the strings always have the same start and end, I would extract everything between "Upgrade starting on" and "with ..." and give it to a date parser

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex to extract part of string from raw string, the following is the whole code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "regexp"
)

func main() {

    // extract part of string using regex
    str := "Upgrade starting on Mon Aug 9 06:46:00 UTC 2021 with ..."

    // extract string "Mon Aug 9 06:46:00 UTC 2021" using regex
    re := regexp.MustCompile(`(Mon|Tue|Wed|Thu|Fri|Sat|Sun) (Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec) \d{1,2} \d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2} (\S{3}) \d{4}`)
    t := re.FindString(str)
    fmt.Println(t)

}
```

Comment: `UTC` part should be taken care to see other possibilities